# Django: Cart matching query does not exist

Tags: django

I've a form that creates a Cart with the text "Random" in a character field, if there is not a Cart object created. This is only to get this recently object's id if it is not already created.

```
cart = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
```

I get an error saying that this query generates an error, however I can see the value of `cart_id` as a cookie so the Query should execute without problem. But it doesn't according to the error message.

> Exception Type:   DoesNotExist
>   Exception Value:   Cart matching query does not exist.

[image]

As you can see in my view, I'm using this:

```
    cart_id = self.request.COOKIES.get('cart_id')
    if not cart_id:
        cart = Cart.objects.create(cart_id="Random")
        cart_id = cart.id
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
```

To get the cookie `cart_id` if it does not exist I created a `Cart object` with the Random text, only to get it's ID.

**Why I'm getting the error?**

**View.py**:

```
class StepOneView(FormView):
    form_class = StepOneForm
    template_name = 'shop/medidas-cantidades.html'
    success_url = 'subir-arte'

    def get_initial(self):
        # pre-populate form if someone goes back and forth between forms
        initial = super(StepOneView, self).get_initial()
        initial['size'] = self.request.session.get('size', None)
        initial['quantity'] = self.request.session.get('quantity', None)
        initial['product'] = Product.objects.get(
            category__slug=self.kwargs['c_slug'],
            slug=self.kwargs['product_slug']
        )

        return initial

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['product'] = Product.objects.get(
            category__slug=self.kwargs['c_slug'],
            slug=self.kwargs['product_slug']
        )
        return context

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print('Step one: form is NOT valid')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        cart_id = self.request.COOKIES.get('cart_id')
        if not cart_id:
            cart = Cart.objects.create(cart_id="Random")
            cart_id = cart.id
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
        item = CartItem.objects.create(
            size=form.cleaned_data.get('size'),
            quantity=form.cleaned_data.get('quantity'),
            product=Product.objects.get(
                category__slug=self.kwargs['c_slug'],
                slug=self.kwargs['product_slug']
            ),
            cart=cart
        )

        response = HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        response.set_cookie("cart_id", cart_id)
        response.set_cookie("item_id", item.id)
        return response
```

**models.py**:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    cart_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Cart'
        ordering = ['date_added']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Comment: You are creating a `Cart` object with `cart_id='Random'` but you're trying to get a `Cart` object with `cart_id=1`. 

2 different data types, 2 different things.

Comment: @PankajSharma the id field is generated automatically when an object is created.

Comment: @Alex yes, and ID must be unique, but "Random" text is generated on every Cart object. I need to create this object like this, to only get its automatically generated id (auto incremented id) afterwards.

Comment: why you are querying for cart again if you have created it (`cart = Cart.objects.create(cart_id="Random")`) , you `cart` directly ?

Comment: @PankajSharma Because the charfield for "Random" is not unique but the id of the recently created object is. And I need to query the last cart created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        cart_id = self.request.COOKIES.get('cart_id')
        if cart_id:
            try:
                cart = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                # supplied ID doesn't match a Cart from your BD
                cart = Cart.objects.create(cart_id="Random")
        else:
            cart = Cart.objects.create(cart_id="Random")
```

No need to create the `Cart` objects, just to get its ID and they hit the DB again to retrieve the same instance.

The idea is:

1. Do you have `cart_id` on session cookies? If so, try to get the `Cart` object based on it.
2. If that fails, it means that the supplied `cart_id` doesn't match an object from your DB
3. If no `cart_id` on session cookies, then simply create your new `Cart` object.

Comment: From where should I import DoesNotExist ?

Comment: My bad. It's called `ObjectDoesNotExist` and it comes from `django.core.exceptions`

More on the subject: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/exceptions/